# displaying names in alphabetical order

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to make a program that prompts the user to enter the number of students in the class, then loops to read in that many names. Once all the names have been read in it reports which student would be at the front of the line and which one would be at the end of the line. You may assume that no two students have the same name.

But my in my output program does not show the right comparison of strings...

Following is my output. ...please help me.

```
Enter the number of students(1 - 25): 5
Enter the name: ali
Enter the name: hamxa
Enter the name: hassan
Enter the name: anjum
Enter the name: java
╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠java ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠java
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Following is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    char name[size], largest[size], smallest[size];
    double num;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of students(1 - 25): ";
        cin >> num;
    } while (num < 1 || num > 25);

    cin.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the name: ";
        cin.getline(name, size);
        if (strcmp(name, largest) > 0)
        {
            largest[size] = name[size];
        }
        if (strcmp(name, smallest) < 0)
        {
            smallest[size] = name[size];
        }

    }

    cout << largest << " " << smallest << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is C masquerading as C++. It also looks suspiciously like homework. I've modified your question tags appropriately until the code is changed to reflect C++.

Comment: @Casey This is not C and will not compile with a C compiler, nor are the people following the C tag likely interested in answering this question. I will rollback your incorrect edit.

Comment: @Casey This is C++ and not C. This is a matter of fact. Please stick to the facts.This may be poorly written C++ but this is C++ nevertheless.

Comment: @casey i think u are new in this field..this is c++

Comment: @casey How did you think it is c?

this is c++

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change `largest[size] = name[size];` to `strcpy(largest, name);`

`largest[size] = name[size]` doesn't make sense, because `largest[i]` equals to (i+1)th symbol, in your case `size = 10`, `largest` is 10 length long so `largest[size]` points to 11th symbol which doesn't exist.

`strcpy` copies one string to another.

Second, you have to set default values for `smallest` and `largest`. Because by default `char[]` equals to some rubbish like `╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠`.

```
char largest[size] = "";
char smallest[size] = "zzzzzzzzz";
```

So your code should be similar to this

```
const int size = 10;
char name[size];
char largest[size] = "";
char smallest[size] = "zzzzzzzzz";
double num;

do
{
    cout << "Enter the number of students(1 - 25): ";
    cin >> num;
} while (num < 1 || num > 25);

cin.ignore();
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter the name: ";
    cin.getline(name, size);
    if (strcmp(name, largest) > 0)
    {
        strcpy(largest, name);
    }
    if (strcmp(name, smallest) < 0)
    {
        strcpy (smallest, name);
    }
}

cout << largest << " " << smallest << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters there is no sense to declare variable `num` as having type `double`.

```
double num;
```

I think the number of names can not be a fraction.

It is better to declare it as having at least type `size_t`

```
size_t num;
```

The character arrays `largest` and `smallest` were not initialized initially. So these conditions in the if statements also do not make sense

```
if (strcmp(name, largest) > 0)
//...
if (strcmp(name, smallest) < 0)
```

You should either initialize the arrays with "empty"  strings or copy to them strings in the main for loop.

Arrays do not have the copy assignment operator. You have to copy elements of one array into another array. For character arrays that contain strings you can use standard C function `strcpy`.

And these statements

```
largest[size] = name[size];
smallest[size] = name[size];
```

try to assign non-existent element of one array to another. They do not copy a string from one array into another.

The program can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    const size_t SIZE = 10;
    char name[SIZE], largest[SIZE], smallest[SIZE];
    size_t num;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the number of students(1 - 25): ";
        std::cin >> num;
    } while (num < 1 || num > 25);

    std::cin.ignore();

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < num; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the name: ";
        std::cin.getline( name, SIZE );

        if ( i == 0 )
        {
            std::strcpy( largest, name );
            std::strcpy( smallest, name );
        }
        else if ( std::strcmp( largest, name ) < 0 )
        {
            std::strcpy( largest, name );
        }
        else if ( std::strcmp( name, smallest ) < 0 )
        {
            std::strcpy( smallest, name );
        }
    }

    std::cout << largest << " " << smallest << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter the number of students(1 - 25): 5
Enter the name: ali
Enter the name: hamxa
Enter the name: hassan
Enter the name: anjum
Enter the name: java
java ali
```